# Login loop problem Ubuntu 18.04 only for new users

Tags: login, lightdm

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new computer.

The first user is fine. New users I created face the login loop problem.

I checked the .Xauthority and .ICEauthority files.
I reconfigured lightDM
I don't suppose the graphic card drivers are bad since the first user works fine.

I am a little stuck here.

Comment: are there enties on this site or other websites refferencing the login loop? I don't know what it is and maybe we should start there.

Comment: There are plenty but:
a) I tried all the suggested fixes (at least the the ones I could find)
b) My issue has the particularity of only happening for new users. I could not find other entries mentioning that aspect (it is usually all or nothing)

Comment: ok I'm reading this : https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/ are you saying that with busybox you can indeed log in and that is how you then checked the secondary user's .Xauthority files?

Comment: also do you experience this issue with communitheme? https://www.ubuntupit.com/ubuntu-communitheme-a-new-ubuntu-community-theme/  && https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-community-theme/

Comment: First step is to tell us exactly *how* you created the new users

Comment: @ tatsu: yes, the secondary user's Xauthority is under the right name.

Comment: @steeldriver: I created one with the command line (sudo adduser username).
I created another one with the "account settings" tool (which has an "add user" button. 
In both cases, the result is the same. 
I also tried to fiddle with the account type (standard vs administrator) but I saw no difference.

Comment: I'd suggest something diagnostic like `sudo -iu testuser namei -l \$HOME/.Xauthority` (replace `testuser` by the username as appropriate) which will verify that the user has a valid login shell AND home directory

Comment: The user name is biasse. Here is what the command returns:

drwxr-xr-x root   root   /  
drwxr-xr-x root   root   home   
drwxr-xr-x biasse biasse biasse  
-rw------- biasse biasse .Xauthority

Comment: Sorry I could not figure out break lines :(